# Saving a different objects into a string in java

Tags: java

I need a bit help in java, I need to save objects into certain positions of the String but it always gives me errors 
and it gives me two errors for each expression 
error ']' expected in   Rectangle pole[i] = new Rectangle(i,i-1);
error illegal start ox expression   Rectangle pole[i] = new Rectangle(i,i-1);

I tried using switch-case but switch-case confused me a bit more so I brought back IF-ELSE but I can't move on.

Thanks very much for help.

```
public class Hello{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String pole[];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<= 9; i++){
        if (i % 3 == 1){
            Rectangle pole[i] = new Rectangle(i,i-1);
        } else {
        if (i % 3 == 2){
            Square pole[i] = new Square(i);
        } else {
            Goofy pole[i] = new Goofy(i);}
    }}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense, did you subclass `String`? And why would you want to store objects as `String`?

Comment: Not to mention that `String pole[];` is missing an actual array initialization and `Rectangle pole[i]` is completely invalid syntax

Comment: "Saving a different objects into a string" - String are definitely not designed to "save objects" - what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I didn't subclass String, function Goofy gives me a string of letters. I'm a bit new to java so I thought that I can use the same logic when I want to make a field of objects. Explanation why I can't do it like in the code above would be helpful as I want to learn it on my own but I can't move on now and I tried many expressions but I can't get to the clue.

Comment: According to your code (`new Goofy(i);`) is a `class` not a function

Comment: My bad, all of them are classes but I named functions by the same names as classes.

Comment: `String pole[]`  or `Rectangle pole[]` or  `Goofy pole[]` ?

Answer (score 0):

String-Array should be `String[] pole = new String[your_length];`

Unfortunately I do not know the class `Rectangle`, but if you just want to store if its a Rectangle or Square you could use: `pole[i] = "Rectangle/Square/Goofy";`